# How to install diesel_cli with "cannot open input file libpq.lib" error?

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-cargo, rust-diesel

I'm trying to install `diesel_cli` on my machine and have run into errors:

```
PS C:\> cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
```

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX64\\x64\\link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc0hfMW4\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.diesel.db6871c2-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.3oc4g8xgeqr3xhil.rcgu.o" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libdiffy-10116d1a46240765.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libansi_term-8ac785ba6dab3d54.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\liburl-085413cf155ebf4e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libidna-e617760a188ae951.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libunicode_normalization-06cbce6ee463ab15.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libtinyvec-2700dcc8ca440a73.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libtinyvec_macros-5d0a0a5267ac9a02.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-3843cd708b9d5313.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libform_urlencoded-bc0ece478c9969ff.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-459d5072c4f6d412.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libdotenvy-d2dbc9637619d426.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libchrono-422b701f158856a2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libnum_integer-2ae42b6e08c222a4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libnum_traits-c406e65b13d6dcc2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libserde_regex-766adf3a555ccd38.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libregex-f7212d89a6f67148.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libaho_corasick-5aae31e8a72badf2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libmemchr-a65d51fb2ae7accd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libregex_syntax-5a1f463340fb2444.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libheck-f97b054e733bf2b0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libclap_complete-007464ddcbb6d7e3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libdiesel_migrations-3bdc5b636ff49b93.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libmigrations_internals-057e468a6688077a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libtoml-761527a98d007259.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libdiesel-3216c6f0692e5464.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libitoa-275f0509159cbce5.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libbyteorder-c046fcd7b7138a94.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libpq_sys-634b13f8c11ea75f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libclap-5c0a23e17fdd1cb3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libatty-8c20fbe3a5f86f4a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libstrsim-3f67262decc03c33.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libtermcolor-2d2dc574ed6f0782.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libwinapi_util-24c50559c3aed431.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libwinapi-e00b279ba3acd452.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libtextwrap-a3c74de9cda85b72.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libclap_lex-ed195b3d1e438c9f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libos_str_bytes-ee2d8aeaa96a27b2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libindexmap-8887803fd6fdd584.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libhashbrown-f256a9213b6968e2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libbitflags-64893d0f4e23f5eb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\libserde-40c8cc7197730aad.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-2e5a4fde2066d4f2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-a4e0bcf1e60e2edb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-2d0f8274a5407337.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd_detect-dc68e6f9c2985e79.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-8bfb058d1afb96bd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-fe2fe9acb704bcf5.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libadler-4e20259a2e504a61.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-ba723ab4066a2120.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-f9ca31420ed0b54e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-753c3a361b9abd1c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-22cf67e3a026b780.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-4bacd70ae093a213.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-2823e3c97f1346a4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-2e984cab75d078cb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-c045e84c0343a063.rlib" "libpq.lib" "advapi32.lib" "cfgmgr32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "kernel32.lib" "msimg32.lib" "ole32.lib" "opengl32.lib" "runtimeobject.lib" "shell32.lib" "user32.lib" "winspool.lib" "advapi32.lib" "userenv.lib" "kernel32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "bcrypt.lib" "msvcrt.lib" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "/OUT:C:\\Users\\Owner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo-installUiMeci\\release\\deps\\diesel-e71e8d3863826309.exe" "/OPT:REF,ICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Owner\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libstd.natvis"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libpq.lib'


error: could not compile `diesel_cli` due to previous error
error: failed to compile `diesel_cli v2.0.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo-installUiMeci`
```

I've installed Rust successfully. I have Postgres 13 running locally and in Docker as well. But I'm still stuck and can't figure out what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please format your question in such a way that it is actually readable. Otherwise the error messages seems to indicate that this is an issue with your environment, so likely it's impossible to other people to help you there. For example the feature cargo claims not to be there [is there](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/1.4.x/diesel_cli/Cargo.toml#L40)

Comment: To future readers: if you're on a Mac you can find more solutions [here](/q/70383711/2189130) and [here](/q/70637566/2189130).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe If you download this solves your problem

https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Answer (score 2):

Please confirm that you have the Postgres development libraries installed:

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```

For more help:

- https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2026
- https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/2465

Answer (score 2):

On windows, after installation of postgresql define environment variable which points to client libs. PQ_LIB_DIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\lib

Answer (score 0):

It's works for me!

```
sudo apt install libpq-dev
```