# rust-lld: error: unable to find library -llibpq

Tags: postgresql, rust, cross-compiling, libpq, rust-diesel

### Useful info

I am building a webapp and using as back-end [rocket.rs](https://rocket.rs/), with [diesel.rs](https://diesel.rs/) to connect to the **Postgres** database. I wanto to dockerize this webapp: I'm on **Windows 11**, and I want to *cross-compile* for Linux alpine, so I can just add the executable in the container.

Toolchain: `nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`

Target: `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`

`Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "project-api"
version = "1.0.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.4.10", default-features = false }
diesel = { version = "1.4.8", features = ["postgres"] }
serde = { version = "1.0.131", features = ["derive"]}
dotenv = "0.15.0"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.10"
default-features = false
features = ["json", "serve", "diesel_postgres_pool"]
```

`.cargo/config.toml` file:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "rust-lld"
```

Compile command: `cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release`

In my `PATH` I already added:

```
.../PostgreSQL/14/bin
.../PostgreSQL/14/lib
.../PostgreSQL/14/include
```

### The problem

When I compile the project, I get the following error:

```
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
...
 = note: rust-lld: error: unable to find library -llibpq
```

This is the complete error:

```
   Compiling project-api v1.0.0 (D:\projects\project-management-system)
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "rust-lld" "-flavor" "gnu" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained\\rcrt1.o" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained\\crti.o" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained\\crtbeginS.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.10.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.11.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.12.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.13.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.14.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.15.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.8.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.project_api.f9c82bac-cgu.9.rcgu.o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7.22qos1iwh0pu1l3f.rcgu.o" "--as-needed" "-L" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps" "-L" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\release\\deps" "-L" "D:/programs/PostgreSQL/14/lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib" "-Bstatic" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libdotenv-17787ac5e36ba405.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\librocket_contrib-908e672c5a94e5a1.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libdiesel-b618b4aafb14a3d4.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libpq_sys-0deff7ab575185bc.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libbitflags-cd7b464110d56932.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libr2d2-17991d433d6b8815.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libscheduled_thread_pool-ed3fe870ef2578f4.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libparking_lot-084e1692fb5bda8c.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libparking_lot_core-57505ee8fbe2715a.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liblock_api-c4af51bd9cc3c613.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libscopeguard-d10f930610969f1b.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libinstant-5b170197aa126111.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libserde_json-f02c39ef48f71da7.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libryu-62ce0cec239f97c8.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libitoa-8ec78a5baa91caac.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\librocket-28b96e263956caad.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libatty-11406b7a761cb014.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libbase64-d9fe97a8863a409c.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libmemchr-1dd949379d427674.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtoml-6efc66767f0cacd7.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libserde-4add0bb05fd83ce8.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libyansi-077b82a357bfe296.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\librocket_http-9426f414126ee4c8.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libhyper-5854b3142fe943a8.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libmime-41e7a782b7da09c1.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liblog-8290fbf24ebfc650.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liblog-52629d6d7adb881b.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libcfg_if-b1347d601d516de4.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liblanguage_tags-1f120d4eb4c64568.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtypeable-37b90a66c0e53fd4.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtraitobject-e42a82912129d07a.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libnum_cpus-2c9ebf56e8506369.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libhttparse-5fdd6843d2b90a53.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libunicase-1ff8862237f0ad7e.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liburl-cb2f1703c2051404.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libidna-2dccc330fa120c40.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libunicode_normalization-05c479f908735c18.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtinyvec-89542cb3fe5ec50d.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtinyvec_macros-0d79dc173afd5963.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libunicode_bidi-25a8617db7cb03aa.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libmatches-5a438e594be46ce5.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libbase64-1d678e0cfd664cb9.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libsafemem-7dc2f1cd7551f3b9.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libbyteorder-2481812d3e7c910d.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libunicode_xid-d2b897ae1242d958.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libstate-d915de2c2db68eef.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libindexmap-3190e1dd9e2809b7.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libhashbrown-4794792eab7bd8e3.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libcookie-b22759f25ba38a69.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libtime-6373f03850cf300d.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\liblibc-d520e3667288b8da.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-ee9e622516b87769.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libsmallvec-2817ef9eba1ed532.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libpercent_encoding-dd42f0c66c80313d.rlib" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\libpear-f2f7fd587bab036d.rlib" "--start-group" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libstd-84fa96c5a6567c2a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-2694d6b5ee3337f3.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-58e7d510a302cb06.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libadler-3b97f36d6f391442.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libobject-7f2f74160dfc1203.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libmemchr-bc62538a6b3d16cf.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libaddr2line-531fc0db5fed2ff4.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libgimli-267be56b670e3626.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libstd_detect-5efe0f28e08ac5c2.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\librustc_demangle-5cb8086f7dea7d11.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libhashbrown-26229185d2048651.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-5e539cff88cca34d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libunwind-a33879496a1412b2.rlib" "-lunwind" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libcfg_if-cb8b44b450e6e086.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\liblibc-9946a456dc1d9b49.rlib" "-lc" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\liballoc-7fa17c9ac5f3bbe0.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-d23d1fdf2f9c2e82.rlib" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libcore-4927c240c984c2ab.rlib" "--end-group" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-ff05cc303f3269e0.rlib" "-Bdynamic" "-llibpq" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-znoexecstack" "-L" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib" "-L" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained" "-o" "D:\\projects\\project-management-system\\target\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\release\\deps\\project_api-565490f9d632eaa7" "--gc-sections" "-static" "-pie" "--no-dynamic-linker" "-z" "text" "-zrelro" "-znow" "-O1" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained\\crtendS.o" "C:\\Users\\user\\.rustup\\toolchains\\nightly-2021-12-05-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-unknown-linux-musl\\lib\\self-contained\\crtn.o"
  = note: rust-lld: error: unable to find library -llibpq
          

error: could not compile `project-api` due to previous error
```

### What I tried

I already tried adding the `libpq.dll` and `libpq.lib` files to the `x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/lib` folder, but I got the same error. I tried adding it to the default target too, but it didn't work. I found out it could be a problem of some `build.rs` file in a library... but I don't know which one. I also tried compiling with the regular nightly toolchain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Diesel error (3 errors) - failed to compile 'diesel\_cli v1.4.1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262864/install-diesel-error-3-errors-failed-to-compile-diesel-cli-v1-4-1)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't: I installed diesel_cli without any problem on my machine. The problem is when I try to cross-compile the project itself from Windows to Linux. 
I got around the problem by compiling the project in Docker directly.
At this point, i think I can use Docker's multi-step build to do the same thing I wanted to do locally.